# NSMutableURLRequest returning null with POST

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutableurlrequest

As per the title, I believe `NSMutableURLRequest` is returning `null` when I add in POST request? My server side is all set up and I am able to `curl -F "test=test" 127.0.0.1` with my desired result.

As you can see from the methods below I have placed a few `NSLog`s for error testing. The `didReceiveResponse` and `connectionDidFinishLoading` methods worked however `didReceiveData` failed to call. Similar as to if I didn't place a POST message when I used curl and results in nothing. From this it leads me to think that I have missed something in the `viewDidLoad` method.

I have also added how I send the response from the server using json encoding at the very bottom.

So have I missed something?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *yourPostString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test=test"];
    dataWebService = [NSMutableData data];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1/"]];
    NSString *postLength =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [yourPostString length]];

    [request addValue:@"text/html; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];    
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[yourPostString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    myConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [myConnection start];  
}

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse     *)response {
    [dataWebService setLength:0];
    NSLog(@"Received Response");   
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [dataWebService appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"working %@", data);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataWebService encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@",responseString);
}
```

Here is the send response function.

```
function sendResponse($status = 200, $body = '', $content_type = 'text/html'){
    $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . getStatusCodeMessage($status);
    header($status_header);
    header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
    echo $body;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, never knew about this feature. :)

Comment: No problem. You just won't get anyone wasting there time on someone that won't give them credit for there work.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question but have you considered using `ASIHTTPRequest` framework. I find it a lot easier to use. Have you also considered using wireshark to see what you are sending and getting back from your request. You could be missing something that needs to be sent.

Comment: I have but it is no longer being updated anymore so I am trying alternatives.

Comment: this code is ok. I've checked it and launched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reqests `Content-Type` should be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`